# Macro to clear contents including format in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear contents including format in column G till the last data in the column. Note column G also has some empty cells in between. I used below code it works fine but it clears data from all columns. Please any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub ClearData()
Range("A3", Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Clear
MsgBox ("Data Cleared")
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Your post says column "G", but your code has column "A", so which one do you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will `ClearContents` and `ClearFormats` from column "G" (starting from "G3" until last row with data in column "G")

```
Sub ClearData()

With Range("G3:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    .ClearContents
    .ClearFormats
End With
MsgBox "Data Cleared"

End Sub
```